# UWP Daily Schedule(TimeLine) Without Toolkit C#

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am currently writting with a group a UWP Application that makes reservations. But we walked into a problem to make a dynamic daily schedule. We wanted to make a daily schedule that shows for an item when its rent that day and for how long. Below you will find a wireframe with the concept in mind.

[image]

Edit:
We have an SQL database with the start and endtime of each reservation and we need to transfer that into a timeline/schedule to show the user on what specific moment the "boat" can still be rent and show the user the moments when its already rent. We dont know how we can approach this, we thought about LiveCharts, WinRTXamlToolkit or with the build in grid/scroll viewer but we dont know how to do that dynamically.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: We dont know any solution to solve this problem.

Comment: But which problem? What have you tried? The wireframe itself is not a "problem", so where are you getting stuck?

Comment: We have a sql database with the start and endtime of each reservation and we need to transfer that into a timeline/schedule to show the user on what specific moment the "boat" can still be rent and show the user the moments when its already rent. We dont know how we can approach this, we thought about LiveCharts, WinRTXamlToolkit or with the build in grid/scroll viewer but we dont know how to do that dynamicly